# Can a read() or write() system call continue where it left off after being interrupted by an EINTR signal?

Tags: c, unix, posix, system-calls, systems-programming

```
ssize_t ret;
while (len != 0 && (ret = read (fd, buf, len)) != 0) {
  if (ret == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR)
      continue;
    perror ("read");
    break;
  }
  len -= ret;
  buf += ret;
}
```

I am wondering how this code can continue where it left off since If it receives an interrupt signal. In that case read() system call has to start again and doesn't it make it start from beginning? Same thing also valid for write() system call. Can you explain how these system call behave with those situations?

Comment: "doesn't itmake it start from beginning?".  No.  Anything that has been read from the stream will not be read again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://linux.die.net/man/3/read

> If a `read()` is interrupted by a signal before it reads any data, it shall return -1 with errno set to `EINTR`.
>
> If a `read()` is interrupted by a signal after it has successfully read some data, it shall return the number of bytes read.

In either case, the next call to `read()` will continue to read where it left off before the call was interrupted.

> If read() does not retrieve all the data in a message, the remaining data shall be left on the STREAM, and can be retrieved by the next read() call.

Comment: IMO It's pretty plain from that definition. If there is no data read, it will return -1. If there was data read, then it returns the number of bytes read. In either way it continues to read where it left off.

Comment: It seem that "continues to read where it left off" does answer the question.

Comment: It continues where it left off, so in the first case was nothing read, so it will keep reading whereever it was before the call started. In the second case it will return the number of bytes read, so the next read will continue reading after where the bytes returned left off.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I gave the link, and there are other sources, saying the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It comes from the comment.  The comment to which you responded "Your comment ... still ignores the ... actual question".  I don't disagree that this answer is incomplete, but the comment does clarify somewhat.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I updated the answer to include that comment, to make it clearer.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The comment was originally not part of the answer, it was added later. Furthermore, you (and the answerer) seem to misunderstand the quoted section: it says nothing about subsequent calls to `read` *after* an `EINTR` signal was handled. It only concerns the interrupted call *itself*. — Devolus’ comment may well be right (these semantics seem reasonable) but I can’t find any confirmation of this.

Comment: `If read() does not retrieve all the data in a message, the remaining data shall be left on the STREAM, and can be retrieved by the next read() call. `

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I added it to the answer aswell, though I think that my original answer was already sufficient. ;)

Comment: Nice and clean explanation. Thx for information.